# Converting frames of a video into images using ffmpeg in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I want to convert all the frames of a video into images in node. Is there any way to get this done using ffmpeg. Searches are not returning any expected results. Actually iam new to node. can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do it using this command which uses the select filter for a set of custom ranges:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='between(t,2,6)+between(t,15,24)' -vsync 0 out%d.png`